# Send a GitHub pull request with a single file change

Tags: github, pull-request

I forked a repo on GitHub, made and pushed changes to my version, and now want to send a pull request to the original repo.

How can I send a pull request with changes affecting a single file and not include the commits and changes done on the other files?

Comment: .. and the problem was? What did not work as expected? Did you get any errors executing your action?

Comment: Simply, I don't what to do

Comment: @matax you now can do it directly on GitHub: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28031667/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new branch from `origin/master`, commit the right changes to it (you can use `git cherry-pick` to copy commits among branches) and create a pull request of that branch.

Comment: origin/master contains other commits made by myself that I don't want to be included in the pull request

Comment: I would create a new branch for them and revert the `master` branch (`git reset --hard`) to the state of the original repo, just for tidiness. However, you can use any other kind of reference provided by Git to create a new branch from the state of the original repo.

Comment: ok I tried but `git reset --hard`don't restore the `master` branch to the orginal repo, maybe because I pushed a lot of commits

Comment: Well, I meant `git reset --hard reference-to-the-original-repo's-state`. You must find actual reference in _your_ log.

Answer (score 5):

You now (January 2015) can do it directly from the GitHub web interface.
See "[Quick Pull Requests](https://github.com/blog/1945-quick-pull-requests)":

> When using your browser to edit a file on GitHub.com, the web-based commit composer lets you quickly propose a change to a new branch and then immediately open a pull request for discussion and review:

[image: Selecting the new branch option to open a quick pull request: cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/296432/4485188/881f7a92-49c6-11e4-83dc-bee67d89c139.gif]

> Reducing the time it takes to open a pull request lowers the contribution barrier, and having this workflow available entirely within the browser makes collaboration more approachable for people with all technical skill levels.

Comment: I just used this.  You are correct, even idiots like me can now contribute.

Comment: @Helzgate Every contribution is welcome: https://twitter.com/terminalbreaker/status/644526894549852161